# DNS redirection UNC path different domain

Tags: redirect, path, dns, unc

We are migrating our old files server. Let's say

srv01.oldDomain.com is the old server (source) with the old domain and srv02.currentDomain.com is the new server (target) in the current domain.

People can reach their documents by means of different ways

1. S:\Doc
2. \servername\Doc
3. \servername.oldDomaine.com\Doc

It is complicated for us to identify where users and even administrators used the third way to reach a document.

I would like to redirect users when they write

\servername.oldDomaine.com\Doc to \servername.newDomaine.com

Is there any way i can accomplish this ? With DNS or an application ?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You can't 'redirect' the users like with HTTP requests (at least as far as i'm aware you can't).

You could just use `cname` DNS entry for `servername` in the in the `oldDomaine.com` zone pointing to `servername.newDomaine.com`.

This is assuming that `Doc` sit's in the the route of each of them?

When you have written in the 'redirect' you have suggested redirecting `Doc` to a root folder?

Comment: Well it is nothing about HTTP. When I'm talking about domain, I mean computer in a domain in opposition with "Workgroup".
cname entry would help with the servername but not the domain.
I would need a UNC path redirection, so when a user writes "\\servername.oldDomaine.com\Doc he is actually redirected to  another server to another domain. 
Hope I'm clear enaugh this time.

Comment: Yeh, i get that. You can't redirect. You *can* cname to a server in a different domain...